# How do I use homebrew to link MacVim and Vim at the same time?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, zsh, vi, macvim

I have used homebrew to install both Vim and MacVim on my mac. Right now, MacVim is the one that is linked. When I run `mvim --version`, I get the most recent and installed version that appears. When I run `vim --version`, the one pre-installed on the computer comes up, even though Vim has been installed via homebrew and is fully up to date. How can I make it so both `mvim` and `vim` link to their respective homebrew installed version, rather than only `mvim` with `vim` not being up to date, or `vim` with `mvim` not working?

Comment: What is your $PATH ?

Comment: Create aliases pointing to the latest version in Cellar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @mmmmmm's comment, run `echo $PATH` in your terminal. Make sure homebrew's path, which is `/opt/homebrew/bin` on M1/Apple Silicone Macs and `/usr/local/bin` on Intel Macs, is before your system's `/usr/bin`

Also run `cat .zprofile` or open your `.zprofile` in your editor of choice. Make sure you have a line like: `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` (M1/Apple Silicone) or `eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"` (Intel). If you want `brew` packages to have precedence over other third-party packages, make sure that line is at the end of the file.